# Terraform loop over list of objects in dynamic block issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create a storage bucket in GCP using Terraform. Please see the below implementation and the .tfvars snippet foe the same

implementation logic

`

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "cloud_storage" {
  for_each = {for gcs in var.storage_buckets : gcs.name => gcs}
  name          = each.value.name
  location      = lookup(each.value, "location", "AUSTRALIA-SOUTHEAST1")
  project       = data.google_project.existing_projects[each.value.project].project_id
  force_destroy = lookup(each.value, "force_destroy", false)
  storage_class = lookup(each.value, "storage_class", "STANDARD")
  labels = merge(
    lookup(each.value, "labels", {}),
    {
      managed_by  = "terraform"
    }
  )
  dynamic "versioning" {
    for_each = [for version in [lookup(each.value, "versioning", null)] : version if version != null]
    content {
      enabled = lookup(versioning.value, "enabled", true)
    }
  }


  dynamic "lifecycle_rule" {
    for_each = [for rule in [lookup(each.value, "lifecycle_rule", toset([]))] : rule if length(rule) != 0]
    content {
      action { 
      type          = lifecycle_rule.value.action.type
      storage_class = lookup(lifecycle_rule.value.action, "storage_class", null)
      }
      condition {
        # matches_suffix      = lookup(lifecycle_rule.value["condition"], "matches_suffix", null)
        age                 = lookup(lifecycle_rule.value.condition, "age", null)
      }
  }
}
  uniform_bucket_level_access = lookup(each.value, "uniform_bucket_level_access", false)

  depends_on = [
    data.google_project.existing_projects
  ]
}
```

`.tfvars snippet`

```
storage_buckets = [
  # this 1st bucket is only defined in DEV tf vars. reason: this bucket is a onetime creation for all DWH cloud artifacts under ecx-cicd-tools project.
  {
    name              = "ecx-dwh-artefacts"
    localtion         = "AUSTRALIA-SOUTHEAST1"
    force_destroy     = false
    project           = "ecx-cicd-tools"
    storage_class     = "STANDARD"
    versioning = {
      enabled = false
    }
    labels = {
      app = "alation"
      project = "resetx"
      team = "dwh"
    }
    uniform_bucket_level_access = false
    folders         = ["alation/","alation/packages/","alation/packages/archive/",
                       "alation/backups/","alation/backups/data/","alation/backups/data/DEV/","alation/backups/data/PROD/"]
    lifecycle_rule = [
      {
        action = {
          type = "Delete"
        }
        condition = {
          age = "10"
        }
      },
    ]
  }
  ,
  {
    name              = "eclipx-dwh-dev"
    localtion         = "AUSTRALIA-SOUTHEAST1"
    force_destroy     = false
    project           = "eclipx-dwh-dev"
    storage_class     = "STANDARD"
    versioning = {}
    labels = {
      app = "dataflow"
      project = "resetx"
      team = "dwh"
    }
    uniform_bucket_level_access = false
    folders         = ["Data/","Data/stagingCustomDataFlow/","Data/temp/","Data/templatesCustomDataFlow/"]
    lifecycle_rule = []
  }
]
```

`

Some have I am unable to make the dynamic block working in the bucket provision logic for the lifecycle_rule section, I am passing a list of objects from .tfvars as I need to be able to add many rules to the same bucket.

It looks like the foreach loop is not iterating over the list of objects in the lifecycle_rule of .tfvars

Below are the errors its throwing. Can someone please assist.

---

Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on storage.tf line 56, in resource "google_storage_bucket" "cloud_storage":
│   56:       type          = lifecycle_rule.value.action.type
│     ├────────────────
│     │ lifecycle_rule.value is list of object with 1 element
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access attribute "action" for a specific element of the list, or across all elements of the list?
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on storage.tf line 57, in resource "google_storage_bucket" "cloud_storage":
│   57:       storage_class = lookup(lifecycle_rule.value.action, "storage_class", null)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ lifecycle_rule.value is list of object with 1 element
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access attribute "action" for a specific element of the list, or across all elements of the list?
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on storage.tf line 61, in resource "google_storage_bucket" "cloud_storage":
│   61:         age                 = lookup(lifecycle_rule.value.condition, "age", null)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ lifecycle_rule.value is list of object with 1 element
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access attribute "condition" for a specific element of the list, or across all elements of the list?

Thank you.

I am expecting it that the dynamic block loop over lifecycle_rule

Answer (score 1):

Your for_each is incorrect. It should be:

```
  dynamic "lifecycle_rule" {
    for_each = length(each.value["lifecycle_rule"]) != 0 ? each.value["lifecycle_rule"] : []
    content {
      action { 
      type          = lifecycle_rule.value.action.type
      storage_class = lookup(lifecycle_rule.value.action, "storage_class", null)
      }
      condition {
        # matches_suffix      = lookup(lifecycle_rule.value["condition"], "matches_suffix", null)
        age                 = lookup(lifecycle_rule.value.condition, "age", null)
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hi @marchin, thank you for your response. some have facing below issue with  your code block. Error: Unsupported attribute type = lifecycle_rule.action.type This object does not have an attribute named "action". storage_class = lookup(lifecycle_rule.action, "storage_class", null) This object does not have an attribute named "action". age = lookup(lifecycle_rule.condition, "age", null)
This object does not have an attribute named "condition".

Comment: @PradeepD Your for each is incorrect, and you were measing value.